# Convert Crystal "if Previous" to SQL

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I am in process of converting all calculations in a Crystal report to SQL. One of the calculations is to identify when a service is a group. I want to add [GroupHours] to the SQL. So, the SQL is:

```
SELECT ServiceID, ServiceDate, Hours, IsGroup 
FROM vSALS
```

The Crystal:

```
if ({vSALS.IsGroup} = 'Yes') // and Previous ({vSALS.Hours}) = {vSALS.Hours} 
   then {vSALS.Hours} * 2 
else //{vSALS.Hours} 0
```

Can anyone help me translate the Crystal into a `[GroupHours]` field in my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you remove the comments from your Crystal code you are left with:

```
if ({vSALS.IsGroup} = 'Yes') then {vSALS.Hours} * 2
```

Which can be written in SQL as:

```
select 
    ServiceID
    , ServiceDate
    , Hours
    , IsGroup
    , case 
        when IsGroup = 'Yes' then Hours*2 
      end as GroupHours
from 
    vSALS
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that's what it ended up being... I'm curious, though, if there actually is a translation for "if Previous" to SQL.  Thoughts?  Thanks again.

Comment: The LEAD and LAG functions provide the functionality to look at next/previous values.